# Firebase: How to persist auth state?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase web sdk without React. I have 4 pages in my application. I am using express js in for each pages to send html file of that route.

I have a file called `common.js` in which I defined methods that will be shared by all pages. In the same file I defined a method to act on auth changed is as following:

> Modified below code

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { firebaseConfig } from './firebase.config';

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);

const addNavbar = () => {
   $('#nav').load('nav.html', () => {
      document.getElementById('btnSignOut').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
         auth.signOut();
      });
   });
}

// createAlert, createEditDeleteButtons, displayLoaderAndHideApp defined here

const unsubscribeOnAuthStateChanged = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
   if (user) {
      window.location.replace('/home');
   } else {
      window.location.replace('/login');
   }
});

export {
   addNavbar, auth, createAlert, createEditDeleteButtons, db, displayLoaderAndHideApp,
};
```

On each page I first call `handleOnAuthStateChanged()`, and it is also called after successful login. I want to persist the auth so I came across [`setPersistence()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence), so I used it in `login.js` and is as follows:

```js
import { browserLocalPersistence, browserSessionPersistence, setPersistence, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth, handleOnAuthStateChanged } from './common';

document.getElementById('btnSignin').addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   try {
      const form = document.querySelector('form.formLogin');
      const email = form.email.value.trim();
      const password = form.password.value;
      await setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence);
      await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      handleOnAuthStateChanged(auth.currentUser); // here auth will retrieve the new logged in user
   } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
   }
});
```

If I use `onAuthStateChanged()` on other pages my user is null then I am stuck in a loop.

Am I missing something?

#### Update

All of the minimal code is after removing all the functionalities except a few that might causing the problem.

I have a file called `nav.html` that is loaded into page by `common.js` and is as defined above.

Code for home, page 1 and page 2 adds navigation by calling `addNav`. Home will import methods from `common.js`, page 2's js, and page 1's js. Home page's js is as following:

```js
import { addDoc, collection, deleteDoc, doc, getDocs, onSnapshot, query, setDoc, where } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { addNavbar, createAlert, createEditDeleteButtons, db, displayLoaderAndHideApp as displayLoader } from './common';
// imports from page 1 and page 2

addNavbar();

// Other methods are defined here...

// Nothing is exported as of now..
```

Comment: Your edit significantly changes the question and makes my answer obsolete. Please don't make such changes to questions, as they make them useless for future visitors. If you my answer led you to a new/different problem (which it did), it is best to either open a new question (preferred) or *add* the new situation without removing the original.

Comment: I guess the cause of the problem is `common.js` called multiple times in a page. I am accepting your answer. The problem is still not resolved trying to reorganize my methods. Thank you for your great support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firebase automatically persists the auth state on most browser environments**, and restores it on app/page reload. To detect this restore of auth state (and other auth state changes) you will need to register an auth state listener with the SDK as shown in the first code fragment in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    const uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

Most of the code of your `handleOnAuthStateChanged` can probably go into this handler.

Comment: Now I understand the problem. I was calling `handleOnAuthStateChanged` on each page rather I should have leave it `common.js`!

Comment: I put `handleOnAuthStateChanged`'s whole logic in `onAuthStateChanged` and it keeps on going for the route `/login`. Note that `onAuthStateChanged`  is defined in `common.js`. Also I removed `setPersistence` from the code as the default is set to [local](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#setpersistence)

Comment: It's hard to say what's going wrong now, without seeing a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the new situation. But the original problems could be solved by using the built-in `onAuthStateChanged` rather than trying to create your own such mechanism.

Comment: I have added some code and also updated `common.js`. As per the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged) `onAuthStateChanged` only triggers when user sign in or sign out. But for my case even after the login the user is null and led to login page.